# How to break RSA when $q = e^{-1} \bmod p$?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, attack

This problem was posed during a recently ended contest.

- I am given a value for n and e. e = 65537. n is a 2048-bit number.
- p is a 1024-bit prime number.
- q is the modular inverse of e mod p. That's the mistake made in this
  problem. q is also non-prime.

Can I use this knowledge to simplify my calculation of the totient function?

Comment: Can you share which contest this is from?

Comment: @yyyyyyy: Gladly! Azure Assassin Alliance 2022 CTF.

Comment: This is not important to the solution, but the key generation ensures that q is [chosen to be prime](https://github.com/sajjadium/ctf-archives/blob/main/AzureAssassinAlliance/2022/crypto/impossible_RSA/server.py#L10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $q = e^{-1}\bmod p$ means there exists an integer $k$ such that $qe = 1 + kp$. Hence
$$ne = pqe = p\cdot(1+kp)/e\cdot e = p + kp^2 \,\text. \label{n-eq}\tag{$\ast$}$$

From $qe=1+kp$, we further get
$$1 \leq k = (qe-1)/p \leq pe/p = e = 65537 \,\text.$$

Thus, to recover $p$, we can iterate over all possible values of $k$ — between $1$ and $65537$ — and try to solve the quadratic equation $\eqref{n-eq}$ over the integers each time.

Comment: My math is a little shaky. For future reference could you explain how you went from qe=1+kp 
to 
1≤k=(qe−1)/p≤pe/p.

Comment: No worries. I'll work it out eventually.